# Combining multiple observations into one line

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I have a 2 column listing of names (in column 1) and systems (in column 2). I am trying to create a table that shows one observation for each person in the list, the count of their name's occurrences, and a listing of systems they have access to.

I'm basing my code off [the example here](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/745.html), but my variables in column 2 are not numeric and I keep getting the warning "NOTE: Invalid numeric data, System='XYZ'" and the table created just has periods in all of the system cells.

My code is below, what am I missing?

```
PROC SQL;

     CREATE TABLE TESTDATA.sorted_import AS

     SELECT Name,
            System format=$15.,
            COUNT(Name) AS Total

     FROM TESTDATA.Master_Test

     WHERE Name <> ""

     GROUP BY Name;

QUIT;

DATA UniqueList (keep= Name System1-System22);
    RETAIN Total Name System1-System22;
    ARRAY UniqueList(*) System1-System22;
    SET TESTDATA.sorted_import;
    BY Name;
    IF first.name then do;
        i=1;
        CALL MISSING(of UniqueList(*));
END;

    UniqueList(i)=System;
    IF last.name then output;
    i+1;
RUN;
```

Comment: Transpose it instead, PROC TRANSPOSE will automatically create the System1-System22 variables instead. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-long-to-wide-using-proc-transpose/

Comment: So I ended up going with the PROC TRANSPOSE route, but now I'm running into an issue with people having multiple roles in one system so it is listing the same system multiple times. How would I keep it to one instance of a system per user? My code is below.               `PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=Sorted_Master_Original 
 OUT=Names_Transposed_Data
 NAME=Nothing
 PREFIX=System;
 BY UserName;
 VAR System;
    RUN;`

Comment: Add a step in between the SQL and PROC TRANSPOSE using PROC SORT that removes duplicates. PROC SORT NODUPKEY option is what you're looking. I'm not aware of an option in PROC TRANSPOSE to remove them, there may be a way via DISTINCT in PROC SQL but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, have you tried defining your array with character variables?:

```
DATA UniqueList (keep= Name System1-System22);
    RETAIN Total Name System1-System22;
    ARRAY UniqueList(*) $ 15 System1-System22;
    SET TESTDATA.sorted_import;
    BY Name;
    IF first.name then do;
        i=1;
        CALL MISSING(of UniqueList(*));
END;

    UniqueList(i)=System;
    IF last.name then output;
    i+1;
RUN;
```

Comment: Well that was easy enough, I feel stupid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

Using an explicit loop over the SET BY group with implicit bookkeeping can be considered cleaner than using an implicit loop with explicit 'bookkeeping' (retain/call missing) and no apriori step for computing group size (`total`).

```
data have (keep=name system);
  do name = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E';
    p = 10 * ranuni(123);
    q = (26 - p) * ranuni(123);
    do c = p to q;
      system = byte(65+c);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data want;
  do total = 1 by 1 until (last.name); /* explicit loop over by group */
    set have;
    by name;
    array list(*) $15 system1-system22;
    list(total) = system;
  end;
  drop system;
run;
```

The implicit bookkeeping is non-data set variables are reset to missing at the top of the implicit loop and an implicit `output` when program flow reaches the bottom of the DATA step.